# Check Checkboxes based on data returned from server - Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, checkbox

I have a registration form where I give users a list of checkboxes that contain skills like (photography, music instruments) the list is huge. On registration the user checks multiple checkboxes based on the skills he/she has. Then I save the users skills in their user document in the database MongoDB.

Below is a basic versions of my user Schema:

```
{ firstName: John,
  lastName: Smith,
  email: john.smith@something.com,
  skills: [
    "photography",
    "music",
    "programming",
    "mathematical skills"
  ]
}
```

**Important Note:**
I have a `Skills` schema in my mongoDB. Which is basically a huge array of skills, a basic example:

```
{ id: 1287638712687312
  allSkills: [
   "photography",
   "music",
   "programming",
   "mathematical skills"
   "another",
   "another",
   and so on
]}
```

**My Question:**

I want the user to be able to edit their skills (remove or add more). I used `ng-repeat` to iterate over all the skills from my `Skills` schema.

What I would like to do is that all the skills that are currently within the users document are already selected within I use `ng-repeat` to show all skills in the edit skills page.

That way the user will easily be able to view the skills they have currently and check or uncheck based on their requirement.

**An example:**

If the user has `music` skills already in their document. And when they go to edit their skills from a huge list of skills the `music` skill is already checked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

```
 {{user.skills}} // contains skills from users document

 <div ng-repeat="skill in completeSkills">
    <label ng-repeat="x in skill.allSkills">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{x}}" ng-checked=""> {{x}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="option in completeSkills ng-checked="user.skills.indexOf(option) > -1" ng-change="toggle(option,user.skills)">
<label>{{ option }}
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.toggle = function (option, options) {
    var index = options.indexOf(option)
    if (index >-1) {
        options.splice(index,1);
    } else {
        options.push(option)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I currently have 2 arrays in my page, first is `user.skills` which contains the users skills selected at registration and other array called `completeSkills` which contains all the skills within the database and I'm using `ng-repeat` to iterate over them. I am having trouble adapting your code to mine. I have updated my question with my code. Any advice will be great.

Comment: Edited the answer with your objects

Comment: Again thank you so much. Could you just explain what are you doing here `indexOf(option) > -1`

Comment: Checks if the option is in the array

Comment: Perfect Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to intersect user vs schema, and give selected=true to those that intersect (meaning they are present in your user, he has the skill).

Which if I am not mistaken is easily done with :

Iterate over allskills while creating the checkboxes, and if they are in user.skills you get them as selected

something along

```
for each allskills  
if(allskills.indexOf(thiselement) > -1) {
    //MARK it as selected
}
```